# Why install a new library and want to use it, it shows an error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I installed galio-frame.`npm install galio-framework` Then I used it.

import : `import { Card } from 'galio-framework';` and then

```
<Card
  flex
  borderless
  style={styles.card}
  title="Christopher Moon"
  caption="139 minutes ago"
  location="Los Angeles, CA"
  avatar="http://i.pravatar.cc/100?id=skater"
  imageStyle={styles.cardImageRadius}
  imageBlockStyle={{ padding: theme.SIZES.BASE / 2 }}
  image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497802176320-541c8e8de98d?&w=1600&h=900&fit=crop&crop=entropy&q=300"
/>
```

And when I run it with npx react-native run-android. I encounter this error. Of course, I have the same problem with installing and using other libraries.

```
  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules\galio-framework\src\index.js -> node_modules\galio-framework\src\Toast.js -> node_modules\galio-framework\src\index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you `link`ed? How did you create your initial project?

Comment: No, I didn't create any links. I installed with ``npx react-native init AwesomeProject``

Comment: So first try to run `npx react-native link` in project dir

Answer (score -1):

Hi Try importing this way,
`import  Card  from 'galio-framework';`